# How can I login as another user with Salesforce API?

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce

I created an script to get some information users send via SMS then create a Contact in Salesforce using that information with the Salesforce API and works fine, but I hard-coded the user and password so every time a user creates a Contact from SMS i´ll be the creator. How can I access user´s credentials for creating the Contact? I want to do something like: select Id from User WHERE Phone = $_GET['mobile'] and then make createdById equal to user's id. Is that possible without having an array or file with user´s passwords?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an application from their app store to send the SMS message or is this native Salesforce functionality?

Comment: It's an external service [world-text](http://www.world-text.com/)  the only thing I do with this SMS service is redirect the text message to a url get the information and map it with Contact Object´s fields to create a Contact.

Answer (score 0):

Answered on success community by David "wOOt!" Liu

You can edit the CreatedById field to anyone you want using Apex - no credentials needed!
Salesforce needs to turn on this permission for your org first - I believe it's called "Create Audit Fields".  This lets you modify fields such as CreatedDate, CreatedById, etc etc.  Many orgs use this so it's actually a fairly common request - I just wrote code recently that changed a record's creator as well.

Some more definitions on Audit Fields can be found here:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm